# Php CURL automatic Login

Tags: php, cookies, curl, jsessionid

This is my first question on this forum but it helped me before by finding answers on it. So I am trying to login automatically to my account using PHP and CURL.

I am new to PHP but until now whenever I needed to connect to a webpage, do a post or a get or follow a redirect everything worked.

The problem is that the account that I am trying to login has a user/password page followed by a memorable word page in which I have to enter some characters from my memorable word.

Now I manage to pass the first page and getting the second page where I have to enter the memorable word characters but when I am trying to do that (so the second post) is not working -  I am redirected to the login again.

Now I tried to investigate to see what is the problem but still I am not sure why is not working. I observed that a JSESSIONID is passed by the server in normal login which is the same, while when I run my script the JSESSIONID changes. I am using:

```
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

But when I check the file it's empty and it hasn't been modified since was created. Amd yes the file can be written (it has 777 rights).

I don't know if this is the problem or something else but I looked for answer and I tried different things and nothing worked. So any ideas would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you absolutely 100% confirmed that your script is running from the working directory that you think it is? Double check with [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php), and make sure the file really is writable by PHP with `var_dump(is_writable('cookie.txt'));`. You should also do `curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);` to get the headers of the response and verify that you actually received some cookies.

Comment: I have run your command for testing if it is writable and it is. It returns true. Regarding the headers I am sure that when I am doing a request to the server some cookies are used because I am using the Live Http Headers plugin from Firefox. Still the file size is 0 B and the last date modified it is when it was created. If I print the headers when I am doing the secons post I get: Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found [1] => Set-Cookie: iApply-PROD-COOKIE=R1294003214

Comment: So @DaveRandom how you can see some cookies are set but not all of them. While when I login normally the JSESSIONID remains the same here when I am doing the second POST is like is not finding it and it generates a new one (like is making another new request).

Comment: Can you edit the question with the request that you see in FireFox, and the request that you see from curl? Preferably both requests (first and second). It's also worth using the FF `User-Agent:` string with your cURL requests to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Provide the code you use to make requests, the one relating to curl resource.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that I can confirm works. It shows you the full path of the cookieJar file and gets the full path from the script's execution location, so it should work on most OSes.

```
<?PHP
$cookiepath = __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'cookieJar.txt';
echo "Saving cookies to: $cookiepath\n";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiepath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiepath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```